# display order of turtles in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I would like the human agents show on top of the octopus agents in the model to improve clarity for the model visuals. Can this be done? How? I have tried display command without success (and googling for solutions without success).

Snapshot of turtles in the world:

[image: snapshot of turtles in the world]

Comment: Hi Emilie and welcome to SO! To get the best chances of receiving help, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your model. Those who read your question should be able to just copy the piece of code you provided and get exactly where you are, and then take it from there.

Comment: in this case there was no obvious snippet of code to share (and the question was quite general I thought). I couldn't share the full code because of future scientific  publications associated with it.

Comment: Yes - just know that normally you won't be asked to share the full code (as you can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)): the point is to create a dummy minimal version of the problem you're experiencing, not your whole program. Anyway, it's true that this problem could be solved regardless (as we did :) ), but it's also true that it is code-based and you tried to solve it code-wise - so from your point of view code was a relevant part. Just pointing those links out to you as I see you're a new user :) That said, please consider accepting the answer if that helped you!

Answer (score 3):

The order according to which breeds are layered in the view is the order in which breeds are declared: breeds declared later will show on top of breeds declared earlier (see [NetLogo User Manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/) > Programming Guide > Breeds).

I imagine that what you have is something like:

```
breed [humans human]
breed [octopuses octopus]
```

If that's the case, try the opposite:

```
breed [octopuses octopus]
breed [humans human]
```

Comment: @EmilieLindkvist - please click the checkmark to the left of Matteo's answer to mark the answer as accepted and the question as closed.